# TableView crashes under uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key x.'

Tags: swift3, tableview

I can't seem to make this tableView with custom cells work. I get a runtime error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key
>   value coding-compliant for the key causeCampaignDescription.'

The weird thing is that that property is not called like that anymore. This is the cell file **MainViewControllerTableViewCell**

```
//
//  MainViewControllerTableViewCell.swift
// 
//
//  Created by on 9/13/17.
//  Copyright © 201. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class MainViewControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var causeCampaignImageView: UIImageView!



    @IBOutlet weak var causeDescription: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var daysToFinishLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var raisedOverTotalLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var percentageCompletedLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var goalProgresView: UIProgressView!


    //card used on
    @IBInspectable var cornerradius : CGFloat = 2

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffSetWidth : CGFloat = 0

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffSetHeight : CGFloat = 5

    @IBInspectable var shadowColor : UIColor = UIColor.black

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity : CGFloat = 0.5



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerradius
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffSetWidth, height: shadowOffSetHeight)
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerradius)
        layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
        layer.shadowOpacity = Float(shadowOpacity)
    }


}
```

and this is the view controller that holds the table view **MainViewController**:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
// 
//
//  Created by on 1/28/17.
//  Copyright © 2017. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import Firebase


class MainViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var campaignRowsData  = [CauseCampaign]()

    var serverFetchCampaignsUrl = Config.Global._serverUrl



    @IBOutlet weak var campaignTableView: UITableView!


    //show navigation controller bar

    var facebookID = "", twitterID = "",firebaseID = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //hide bar from navigation controller

        setToolbar()

        campaignTableView.delegate=self

        campaignTableView.dataSource=self

        campaignTableView.separatorColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)

        recoverUserDefaults()

        getCampaignList()



        //print(facebookID, twitterID, firebaseID)

    }


    func setToolbar(){
        //hide bar from navigation controller
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.purple



    }

    func getCampaignList(){

        Alamofire.request(serverFetchCampaignsUrl+"/campaigns/get/all/user/\(twitterID)/firebase/\(firebaseID)/cat/0", method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):


                let campaignCausesJSON = JSON(campaignCausesData: data)

                self.parseCampaignCausesListResponse(campaignCausesJSON)

                //alternative thread operation


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.campaignTableView.reloadData()

                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }

    func parseCampaignCausesListResponse(_ campaignCausesJSON:JSON){

        if let activeCampaignCount = campaignCausesJSON["active_campaigns_count"].string {
            //Now you got your value
            print("TOTAL_ACTIVE_CAMPAIGNS",activeCampaignCount)
            CampaignsGlobalDataManagerUtil.campaignTotalCount = Int(activeCampaignCount)!
        }

        if let contributorUserId = campaignCausesJSON["contributor_user_id"].string {
            //Now you got your value
            print("CONTRIBUTOR_USER_ID",contributorUserId)
            CurrentUserUtil.contributorUserId = contributorUserId
        }

        if let userTwitterFollowersQty = campaignCausesJSON["user_twitter_followers_qty"].int {
            //Now you got your value
            print("USER_TWITTER_FOLLOWERS_QTY",userTwitterFollowersQty)
            CurrentUserUtil.twitterFollowersCount = Int(userTwitterFollowersQty)
        }

        //Parsing campaigns object array

          campaignCausesJSON["camp_array"].arrayValue.map({

            let campaignCause:JSON = $0

             parseCampaign(campaignCause)
          })




    }
    //TODO:CHANGE TO DATATAPE OBJECT
    func parseCampaign(_ causeCampaign:JSON){

        let causeCampaignObject: CauseCampaign = CauseCampaign();

        causeCampaignObject.description = causeCampaign["cause_description"].stringValue


        causeCampaignObject.id = causeCampaign["campaign_id"].stringValue


        if let contributorsQty = causeCampaign["contributors_qty"].int{
            causeCampaignObject.contributorsQty = contributorsQty

        }

        causeCampaignObject.currencySymbol = causeCampaign["currency_symbol"].stringValue

        if let currentContributions = causeCampaign["current_contributions"].float{
            causeCampaignObject.currentContributions = currentContributions

        }

        if let goal = causeCampaign["goal"].float {
            causeCampaignObject.goal = goal
        }

        if let goalPercentageAchieved = causeCampaign["goal_percentage_achieved"].float{
            causeCampaignObject.goalPercentageAchieved = causeCampaign["goal_percentage_achieved"].float!
        }

        causeCampaignObject.hashtag = causeCampaign["hashtag"].stringValue

        causeCampaignObject.name = causeCampaign["name"].stringValue

        if let remainingAmmountToGoal = causeCampaign["remaining_ammount_to_goal"].float{
            causeCampaignObject.remainingAmmountToGoal = remainingAmmountToGoal
        }

        if let picUrl =  causeCampaign["pic_url"].stringValue as? String {
            causeCampaignObject.picUrl = picUrl
        }

        if let campaignStartingDate = causeCampaign["created_at"].string{
            causeCampaignObject.campaignStartingDate = campaignStartingDate
        }

        if let campaignEndingDate = causeCampaign["campaign_ending_date"].string{
            causeCampaignObject.campaignEndingDate = campaignEndingDate

        }


        var foundationsArray = [Foundation]()

        causeCampaign["foundations"].arrayValue.map({

            let id = $0["foundation_id"].stringValue
            let twitterUsername = $0["twitter_username"].stringValue
            let picPath = $0["pic_path"].stringValue
            let name = $0["name"].stringValue

            let foundation:Foundation = Foundation(id,twitterAccount: twitterUsername,picPath: picPath,name: name)

            foundationsArray.append(foundation)
        })


        causeCampaignObject.foundations = foundationsArray


        campaignRowsData.append(causeCampaignObject)

//        foundations = "<null>";

//innecesario
//        SACAR DE LA REQUEST INICIAL???
//        "went_inactive_date" = "<null>";
//        "tweet_id" = 900936910494810112;


    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return campaignRowsData.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = campaignTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "campaignCell", for: indexPath) as! MainViewControllerTableViewCell

    //setting card attributes
        print("ROW",campaignRowsData[indexPath.row].description)
        let campaignCause:CauseCampaign = campaignRowsData[indexPath.row]

        if let desc = campaignCause.description as? String{
                cell.causeDescription.text = desc
        } else {
            print("NULL")
        }

        return cell
    }


    func recoverUserDefaults(){
        if let fbID = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Config.Global._facebookIdUserDefaults) as? String {
            facebookID = fbID
        }else{
            print("FACEBOOK ID IS NULL")
        }



        if let twtID = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Config.Global._twitterIdUserDefaults) as? String{
            twitterID = twtID
        }else{
            print("TWITTER ID IS NULL")
        }


        if  let firID = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Config.Global._firebaseIdUserDefaults) as? String{
            firebaseID = firID
        }else{
            print("TWITTER ID IS NULL")
        }

        return
    }



}
```

1. The app crashes if the line `reloadData` is uncommented (I don't even know when and If I should use this)
2. If I set a label you can't see anything on screen, I see blank cards, but again, as soon as I uncomment `reloadData` it crashes
3. There's no `causeCampaignDescription`, now it's called `causeDescription` so I don't know why the error keeps mentioning that field
4. The data `desc` is ok since I printed it and it has the right content so it's not that

What could be the problem?

Comment: search for 'causeCampaignDescription' all over the code. You might have forgotten to remove it from interface builder(Storyboards/Xibs)

Comment: You renamed `causeCampaignDescription` to `causeDescription`, but your storyboard or NIB most likely still has a reference to the old name. Go to that field in IB and check the outlets for that control. I bet you'll find that old name still referenced there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the project for `causeCampaignDescription` will often turn up the offending xib and/or storyboard containing the outdated key path. However, it's been my experience that Xcode is not always 100% reliable about finding things in xibs and storyboards, so if Xcode's search feature won't find it, this command in the Terminal will turn it up straightaway:

```
find /path/to/your/project/directory -name .git -prune -or -type f -exec grep causeCampaignDescription {} \; -print
```

Once you find the offending item in the xib or storyboard, change it to the correct string and you should solve your problem.

Comment: you are the best my friend. Thank you very much. I'm new to ios and I trusted to much on xcode managing changes properly on storyboard. I've seen videos lately recomending not to use storyboard...I will think it twice before using it again...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6yz5oX5iWc